# 2.81 - Key frames not working? Shader emission settings?

Tags: keyframes

I have just been seeing if I could do a tutorial on a title animation, but the keyframes in 2.81 seem to not work properly? I set a keyframe in the shader editor and it sometimes sets and sometimes doesn't, then sometimes I can't see the frames at all.
The emission shader is what I am trying to set for animation. The other non-shader lights on a circle path, animate fine.  Is this a bug?

Comment: You need to click on the shader node to be able to see the keyframes for it.

Comment: This is partially answering the question and does help, but how do I see the frames with the "non-linear animation timeline"? Is this not an option and It is just the long way of using two different lines at different times to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the items in the *Dope Sheet* are filtered to only show the selected keys.

To change this you can **uncheck** *Only Selected* in the *Dope Sheet* filter as shown:

[image: Dope Sheet Filter]

Comment: Unrelated question: I like the idea of a compressed font so you can see more of the labels, which font are you using and how?

Comment: @PJMDesign *Preferences → Interface → Text rendering* set to Roboto Condensed (TTF available free from google) with full hinting.